# Javascript FileReader onload not firing

Tags: javascript, html

I haven't used JavaScript in a while and I can't seem to read a text file and display the contents.

I've tried `onload` as well as `onloadend`. If I just put `reader.onload = alert('Hello');` the alert fires, but I can't get anything to work with the function.

Not exactly sure where to go from here. I've tried defining the function after `reader.onload = function(evt)...` but that doesn't work.

I've tried in Safari 6.0.5 and Chrome as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>                                                                    
<html>                                                                             
<head>                                                                         
    <title>Pi to Colors</title>                                                
</head>                                                                        
<body>                                                                         
<script>                                                                       
function readFile() {                                                       
    var reader = new FileReader();                                             
    reader.onload = readSuccess;                                            
    function readSuccess(evt) {                                             
        var field = document.getElementById('main');                        
        field.innerHTML = evt.target.result;                                
    };                                                                      
    reader.readAsText("/pi.txt");                                              
}                                                                           
</script>                                                                      
<div id="main">                                                                

</div>                                                                         
</body>                                                                        
</html>
```

Comment: So you're running this code in a browser? Trying to read a local file off your system? I'm pretty sure the browser prevents you from doing that. What does your browser console tell you?

Comment: The error console does not say anything. Not in Safari.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't grab a local file like that for security reasons.

Another underlying problem is that readAsText (and all the read functions) need the file's content and not its file path/name.  You can grab this from the files collection of the input type="file" element.  Here is how your code could work:

```
function readFile(file) {                                                       
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = readSuccess;                                            
    function readSuccess(evt) { 
        var field = document.getElementById('main');                        
        field.innerHTML = evt.target.result;                                
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);                                              
} 

document.getElementById('selectedFile').onchange = function(e) {
    readFile(e.srcElement.files[0]);
};
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/ngXBV/1/

**Note:** this code not work in safari browser

Comment: "reader.onload = readSuccess;" Shouldn't 'readSuccess' be 'readSuccess()'?

Comment: No, it would assign "undefined" which is the return value of the function.

Comment: [My variation on this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u54za9sp/) demonstrates my problem, you can't use `addEventListener('onload', readSuccess)`, despite the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) : "Note: As FileReader inherits from EventTarget, all those events can also be listened for by using the addEventListener method."

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax to get the content of your file:

```
var reader= new XMLHttpRequest();
reader.open('GET', '/pi.txt');
reader.onreadystatechange =readSuccess();
function readSuccess(evt) {                                             
   var field = document.getElementById('main');                        
   field.innerHTML = reader.responseText;                                
};
reader.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same the problem and I found a solution. You can't read the local file unless the user has permission. You can put a `<input type="file">` on your page. When the file input change, you can read the data.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing worked for me. Below you can find my ugly solution, but it was the only one that did the job. In my case the user can upload up to 3 files, so the var iPDF can be 0,1,2.

```js
 var iPDF=UpdatedExistingNumberOfPDFfiles;
 if (iPDF < NoMaxPDFfiles) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[iPDF-UpdatedExistingNumberOfPDFfiles]);
  reader.onload = function (){
  var PDFdataURL = reader.result;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "Observation_PDFUpload.php",true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var NumberOfPDFfile = iPDF+1;
  xhr.send("PDFfileURL="+PDFdataURL+"&PDFfileName="+PDFfileName+"-Annex-"+NumberOfPDFfile);
  iPDF++;
  if (iPDF < NoMaxPDFfiles) {
   reader.readAsDataURL(files[iPDF-UpdatedExistingNumberOfPDFfiles]);
   reader.onload = function (){
   PDFdataURL = reader.result;
   var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr1.open("POST", "Observation_PDFUpload.php",true);
   xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   NumberOfPDFfile = iPDF+1;
   xhr1.send("PDFfileURL="+PDFdataURL+"&PDFfileName="+PDFfileName+"-Annex-"+NumberOfPDFfile);
   iPDF++; 
   if (iPDF < NoMaxPDFfiles) {
   reader.readAsDataURL(files[iPDF-UpdatedExistingNumberOfPDFfiles]);
   reader.onload = function (){
   PDFdataURL = reader.result;
   var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr2.open("POST", "Observation_PDFUpload.php",true);
   xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   NumberOfPDFfile = iPDF+1;
   xhr2.send("PDFfileURL="+PDFdataURL+"&PDFfileName="+PDFfileName+"-Annex-"+NumberOfPDFfile);
   } 
   }   
  
   }
  }
  }
  };
```