# Why is this FileReader onload not firing?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am starting with this working JavaScript code:

```
  // Begin File Open Code. 
  function fileOpen()
  {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('iDisplay');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e)
    {
      file = fileInput.files[0];
      var imageType = /image.*/;
      if (file.type.match(imageType)) 
      {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {                 
          iDisplay.innerHTML = "";
          image = new Image();
          image.src = reader.result;
          image.id = "I";               // Add an id attribute so the image editor code can access the image.  
          iDisplay.appendChild(image);
          image.onload = function()
          {
            c = document.getElementById("canvas1"); 
            context = c.getContext("2d");
            c.width = image.width; 
            c.height = image.height; 
            context.drawImage(image,0,0);  
          }                
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);             
        moreFiles++;  
        document.getElementById("fileInput").disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById("fileInputD").innerHTML = '<p>Please refresh page to open a new image</p>'; 
      }
      else
      {
        iDisplay.innerHTML = "File type not supported."
      }
  }); 

}
// End File Open Code
```

And trying to break it up into two separate functions, fileOpen() and loadImage().  The reason is that loadImage will also be used to load default images. I came up with several non-working versions. After reading about the topic here, most recently this answer [Javascript FileReader onload not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542907/javascript-filereader-onload-not-firing) I adjusted the code as follows:

```
  // Begin File Open Code 
  function fileOpen(radio)
  {

    fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('iDisplay');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e)
    {
      file = fileInput.files[0];
      var imageType = /image.*/;
      if (file.type.match(imageType)) 
      {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fileSelected; 
        function fileSelected(e)
        {                 
          iDisplay.innerHTML = "";
          image = new Image();
          image.src = reader.result;
          image.id = "I";               // Add an id attribute so the image editor code can access the image.  
          iDisplay.appendChild(image);
          image.onload = loadImage(); 
        }
      }
      else
      {
        iDisplay.innerHTML = "File type not supported."
            }
    })      
  }         
  // End File Open Code 

  // Begin Load Image Code - This will be used to load a preselected image  
    function loadImage()
    {
        c = document.getElementById("canvas1"); 
        context = c.getContext("2d");
        c.width = image.width; 
        c.height = image.height; 
        context.drawImage(image,0,0);  

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);             
        document.getElementById("fileInput").disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById("fileInputD").innerHTML = '<p>Please refresh page to open a new image</p>'; 
      }
      // End Load Image Code
```

But, after reviewing in the Chrome Inspector, the code never gets past

```
    reader.onload = fileSelected;
```

After that line, the function exits, and nothing is loaded.  I have spent hours on variations of this code and cannot get it to fire past that line.  So, my question is "why?"  I should note that I want to stay with pure JavaScript.

**Thank you** in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug in Chrome 73 where it isn't fired if you have a `debugger` statement.

I literally have

```
        reader.readAsText(blob); 
        debugger;
```

and it never hits the `onload`

If I change it to

```
        debugger;
        reader.readAsText(blob);
```

then it works.

Fixed by Chrome 75.

Comment: Wooowwwwww!! Great!!!! Getting mad with this and you are on the target!! Thanks mate

Comment: I reported and they confirmed. But it was already fixed - probably accidentally. I’ll post the link later

Comment: @EliasMP and how long did you spend on this one lol. Took me hours to figure out was it angular, was it rxjs, was it my code. Ugh!

Comment: It was in 1 day x 8 hours per day. But I was doing another project at the same time... Trying this one, and when I didnt figure out keeping doing my stuff... In any case, so much for just 5 lines of code LOL XD XD

Answer (score 1):

You can also use FileReader.readAsDataURL() to parse the file from your . This will create a string in memory containing a base64 representation of the image.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<img id="output"/>
<script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Ref: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded/27165977#27165977)

Comment: I'm loading the image into an HTML5 canvas.  Will that work as a base64 string?

Comment: Yes, it will . Ref: This example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938686/can-i-load-a-local-file-into-an-html-canvas-element

Comment: 6 am here, I will check it out when I can see straight. Thanks. Note: I don't think this will resolve the FIleReader onload issue.

Comment: I got the same issue, sometimes works properly, but sometimes not work, even also `onloadend()` not fire any events.