# FileReader.readystate stuck at 1. Onload is not fired

Tags: angular, angular7, filereader, onload, readystate

I am quite newbie in **angular7** and I just trying to get data from an input type file in the *html file*. I am not getting it. I got the name and different specifications of the file, but not the proper data of it.

The point is **readystate** doesnt change to 2, so **result** property never is fill it and I cant get the data so.

As far as I got it:

**TS**

```
onChange(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = this.saveImage(reader, event);
  }
}

private saveImage (reader: FileReader, ev: ProgressEvent): any {
  this.userInfo.Imagen = (reader.result as string).split(',')[1];
  this.converted_image = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.base64 + this.userInfo.Imagen);
  return null;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" capture style="display:none" #fileInput (change)="onChange($event)"/>
```

But I dont recover any data at all.

Thanks mates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... Quite odd and hoping this answer help you all or, at least, give you a clue about this situation.

Chrome version, from **73** to **75** (fixed in it) has a problem when an **event** collides with a **debugger command** or *break point* by IDE (*debugger command* in fact).

The solution is just eliminate any **debugger command** in the cycle of raising and launching the event and its event method.

Comment: The idea original is coming from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091937/why-is-this-filereader-onload-not-firing/55703594#55703594 (check the reputation of user who post it). But for me is not still working. I delete breakpoint from when I instance the filereader until onload method is fired and now is working for me.

Comment: As far you are criticizing my answer without checking it. Please rate it (with an upvote) for the question, for taking care of posting the extendend answer, and researching again for finding the source as you required... I think is quite far doing that for helping and reward the efford of user of our community :)

Comment: Really man? It is a bug known for Chrome. And it is working for me, resolving the problem... Dont be a child...

Comment: You know we are speaking about a reported and recognized error in chrome... And you are voting down... You are amazing... Really. The best!